# Telegram: Contact a user by Id

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'd like to contact a user by his id instead of his username

https://t.me/ID_USER like https://t.me/732189738218

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can.
you can call `SendMessage`  method and specify `chat_id` parameter.
also you can add contact by `chat_id`. [please see *Raw API Docs*]
but you can't search/get full user info. public fields only!

Answer (score 0):

No sir unfortunately you can't do that. Telegram Bot API doesn't return phone number. You should either use Telegram API methods instead or ask it explicitly from the user. You cannot get "friends" of a user as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I mean telegram Id, not telephone number.

Comment: yes sir it won't allow you to search by Id. its more convinient just do it by name and then tap on chat a new window will confront you

Comment: gotcha. but some user doesn't set the username